# Converting JSON data into CSV spreadsheet

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert a JSON file that has headers and numeric data into a CSV file. I am super new to python and know I'm missing some information, but I'm not sure exactly what I need to be looking for.

This is the code that I've tried so far:

```
import json
import csv

with open('my_json_file.json', 'r') as data:
    global invt_data
    invt_data = json.load(data)

with open('my_csv_file.csv','w') as inverter_data:
    writer = csv.writer(inverter_data)
    writer.writerows(invt_data)

inverter_data.close()
```

This writes to the file that I want, but it's only creating three rows with the data titles and none of the values.I'd greatly appreciate any help or pointers in the right direction! Thank you!

I've recently edited my code to try a new approach:

```
import json
import csv

with open('/Users/cpiephoff/Desktop/2019_09_16_INVT_2.json','r') as data:
     global invt_data
     invt_data = json.load(data)

time_data = invt_data['Timeseries']
power_data = invt_data['power_true_kw']
frequency_data = invt_data['power_frequency']

inverter_data = open('/Users/cpiephoff/Desktop/2019_09_16_INVT_2.csv','w')
csvwriter = csv.writer(inverter_data)

for time in time_data:
    csvwriter.writerows(time.values())

for power in power_data:
    csvwriter.writerows(power.values())

for frequency in frequency_data:
    csvwriter.writerows(frequency.values())

inverter_data.close()
```

With this approach, my timeseries throws the error

> str has no attribute value

and the power and frequency data throws the error

> float has no attribute value

How can I fix this so that I can get the data to the csv file?

#### Sample JSON data:

```
{"Timeseries": ["2019-04-01T16:00:00+00:00",
                "2019-04-01T16:01:00+00:00",
                "2019-04-01T16:02:00+00:00"],
 "power_true_kw": [125.5, 127.8, 129.9],
 "power_frequency": [60.0, 59.9, 60.1]}
```

Comment: By "variable headers" do you mean that not every element in the JSON file is composed of the same data elements? So you'll end up with a CSV that has all of the column headers seen throughout the JSON file, but each row may not have an entry for each column?

Comment: Any chance you can provide a couple of sample JSON entries that illustrate the problem?

Comment: @Engineero I understand now that my wording was not good with "variable headers". there's data in every column. here's the json file: {
    "Timeseries": [
        "2019-04-01T16:00:00+00:00",
        "2019-04-01T16:01:00+00:00",
        "2019-04-01T16:02:00+00:00"
    ],
    "power_true_kw": [
        125.5,
        127.8,
        129.9 
    ],
    "power_frequency": [
        60.0,
        59.9,
        60.1
    ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of lists of equal length which are your column data, and need to transpose them into rows.

You can use the [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) built-in function to do this: given some iterables, it will iterate over them simultaneously, producing tuples containing the first element in each iterable, the the second element in each until the shortest iterable is exhausted

```
>>> cols = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
>>> list(zip(*cols))
[('a', 'd', 'g'), ('b', 'e', 'h'), ('c', 'f', 'i')]
```

This  technique can be applied to the data dictionary's [values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) to produce the csv file.

```
with open('outfile.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    # Write the headers
    writer.writerow(list(invt_data.keys()))
    # Write the data
    writer.writerows(list(zip(*invt_data.values())))
```

Produces this file:

```
Timeseries,power_true_kw,power_frequency
2019-04-01T16:00:00+00:00,125.5,60.0
2019-04-01T16:01:00+00:00,127.8,59.9
2019-04-01T16:02:00+00:00,129.9,60.1
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). Pandas is a pretty rich data management tool for Python. It can be a bit tough to wrap your head around at first, but it's super useful and provides a lot of utilities for data analysis and manipulation. To [import your data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.read_json('my_json_file.json')
```

You can preview your data with [`df.head()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html), or look at information about the dataframe with [`df.info()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html) and summary statistics with [`df.describe()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html). I suspect you have rows that do not have entries for every column based on your statement that the JSON file has "variable headers". You can decide how you want to handle these rows and apply, for instance, [linear interpolation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) for missing values with:

```
df.interpolate(method='linear', inplace=True)
```

Alternatively you can [fill missing values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with, for example, zeros:

```
df.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
```

You can then [write to a CSV file](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) with:

```
df.to_csv('my_csv_file.csv')
```